# Does bitlocker encrypt Bios

Tags: bios, bitlocker

Just a basic question. Does full disk encryption (such as bitlocker) encrypt the Bios or just the OS. I know a TPM is required, so that makes me think the Bios is encrypted but I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure why you're asking... actually encrypting the BIOS doesn't really make sense, since you don't store any data there that would need to be protected from curious eyes.

And flashing a modified, unsigned firmware image is usually not easy on a modern system, at least not without having physical access.

To answer your question... bitlocker only encrypts the harddisk, respectively the OS.
If you want to prevent users from accessing the BIOS then you should check whether your BIOS allows you to set a password. Many modern systems allow locking the BIOS via password. Just make sure you don't forget it, else you're locked out of your system as there's no regular recovery method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wish I could +1 but sadly I can't at the moment. I was asking cause I'm currently taking A+, and wanted to have a better understanding of BIOS. Your answer was extremely helpful.

Comment: I also wanted to ask, are CMOS chips still ROM ? I have read 2 conflicting reports. Some say that they are not longer made of CMOS and are instead flash (meaning they are not ROM).

Comment: I think I understand now. Modern CMOS chips are now EEPROM. Sorry for the silly questions